# AccelerometerReadingEventArgs Cannot be found. I added the reference

Tags: c#, frameworks, xna

I am trying to finish up a tutorial, and I am trouble with AccelerometerReadingEventArgs.  I have added the Microsoft.Devices.Sensor and I have stated the using Microsoft.Devices.Sensors
  I have access to AccelerometerReadingAsyncEventArgs but this isn't exactly what I need. I am using 2.0.5  and I think I need to update, but not sure how to do it.  Any help would be great!

Should I be seeing AccelerometerReadingAsyncEventArgs if I have the newest XNA framework? or should I be seeing AccelerometerReadingEventArgs??

Comment: What exactly is the question?  How to update your version of XNA??

Comment: If that would fix my problem then yes, but that is just a guess, as I am not sure if the current version uses AccelerometerReadingAsyncEventArgs anymore(which intellisense brings up, even though I want just AccelerometerReadingEventArgs).  But I just installed XNA 4.0 a week ago...didnt think it would be already outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, you should see AccelerometerReadingEventArgs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604984(XNAGameStudio.40).aspx

It sounds like you have an incorrect version of an assembly referenced somewhere. What happens if you start a brand new project, add the reference, and then try to reference this type? do you see it?

Comment: I will try that when I get home, I am pretty sure the same thing happens though, as the project I am working on is fairly new.